# Using the 'substitute' function within sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I have a database with many outcome variables and only a couple of grouping variables. I am in the middle of writing a graphing function that will allow me to graph many different combinations of IVs and DVs so that all the graphs look the same. The function will mean that in order to generate a new graph I only need to specify the name of the IV, the name of the DV and the label and title of the graph.

I have used the 'substitute' function to good effect so far but have hit a roadblock trying to calculate standard error. It seems the sapply function doesn't allow the substituted variables to be passed into the function it applies.

I have constructed a pared-down version of the problem to illustrate and ask for help on alternatives to either substitute or sapply.

First the toy data

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(groupIV1 = factor(rep(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), 4)),
                  groupIV2 = factor(rep(c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD"), 4)),
                  score1 = runif(16, 0, 10),
                  score2 = runif(16, 3, 7))
```

Now the function for calculating the per-group standard error

```
groupSEs <- function (condGroup, IVGroup, colDV) {
  SE <- sd(df[df[,IVGroup] == condGroup, colDV])/ sqrt(nrow(df[df[,IVGroup] == condGroup,]))
  return(SE)
}
```

Now name all the levels in the two grouping variables as vectors

```
groupSubset <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")
groupSubset2 <- c("groupA", "groupB", "groupC", "groupD")
```

With this function we can then calculate standard error with multiple combinations of IVs and DVs like so:

```
SEsIV1DV1 <- sapply(groupSubset, function(x) groupSEs(x, "groupIV1", "score1"))
SEsIV1DV2 <- sapply(groupSubset, function(x) groupSEs(x, "groupIV1", "score2"))
SEsIV2DV1 <- sapply(groupSubset2, function(x) groupSEs(x, "groupIV2", "score1"))
SEsIV2DV2 <- sapply(groupSubset2, function (x) groupSEs(x, "groupIV2", "score2"))
```

So that works fine. However if I want to put the sapply function inside another function so that I only need to call the level names, IV name, and DV Name like this:

```
applyGroupSE <- function (IVLevels, IVName, DVName) {
  SError <- sapply(IVLevels, function(x) groupSEs(x, substitute(IVName), substitute(DVName)))
}
```

....when i call it....

```
applyGroupSE(groupSubset, "groupIV1", "score1")
```

....it doesn't work. and I get the error message:

```
Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

I figure it is the substitute function not working within sapply for some reason.

However it does work on other functions quite happily. Such as this extraction function.

```
shrinkDF <- function (IVName, DVName) {
  cols <- c(substitute(IVName), substitute(DVName))
  newFrame <- df[,cols]
  return(newFrame)
}

shrinkDF("groupIV1", "score2")

shrinkDF("groupIV2", "score1")
```

Can anyone tell me why 'substitute' works for the latter function but doesn't work with function that use sapply and how I might get around this?

Comment: This might have something to do with the following quote from `?lapply`: `For historical reasons, the calls created by ‘lapply’ are unevaluated`. As stated on the help page, `sapply` is a wrapper of `lapply`. I checked that `vapply` works nicely here. Using `substitute` is unnecessary in this "pared-down" version of your problem, but I can only guess that there is some reason for using it in the original setting.

Comment: Yes I know the sapply isn't strictly necessary here, this was just to illustrate the fact that sapply doesn't accept the substitute function.